# Searching NSArray for an object

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, predicate

I have `NSArray` consisting of `NSDictionary` objects. Need to find index in `NSArray` of object with matching key name in `NSDictionary`. Dictionary has only 1 element. What is the fastest way of doing that? Filter with predicate and then use indexOfObject?

Answer (score 0):

That method would certainly work, but if you're looking for speed, you need to change your structure. Arrays aren't meant to be searched this way. However, it's what `NSDictionary` was built for. If you have a unique key you're searching for, why not store your dictionaries in an `NSDictionary` and use the much, much faster `objectForKey:` method?

If you also need to maintain an ordering, you could create a custom "ordered dictionary" class using an `NSMutableArray` of the keys in your dictionary.

Comment: I don't really imagine how to use `objectForKey` in case I have single `NSDictionary` objects in parent `NSDictionary`. Say I convert my `NSArray` to `NSDictionary`, then the parent keys will be indexes containing dictionary elements with some keys I have to search! So it's like this `0=>[key1=>val1], 1=>[key2=>val2], N=>[keyM=>valM], etc..`. Given by `keyM` I want to know the `N`. I'm not sure even how to build a predicate to access dictionary, so can't build my own version ^^

Comment: I was suggesting you use the keys (your `key1`, `key2`, and so on) as the parent dictionary's keys, not use the would-be indices as the parent dictionary's keys. If your ordering is important and speed isn't an issue, just go with your original plan.